# How to extend default Azure AppService timeout?

Tags: azure, powershell, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, timeout

I'm trying to upload video files through my web application hosted on Azure.

For files bigger than approximately 1.8Gb, I get a Timeout Error 500.

I did some changes in order to extend this timeout with no success:

1. Activited the 'Always On' feature
2. set SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT to 2400 seg on the App settings in Azure panel
3. set WEBSITE_SCM_IDLE_TIMEOUT_IN_MINUTES to 60 min
   on the App settings in Azure panel
4. Tried to run this command on powershell:

   ```
   Get-AzureVM –ServiceName “MyService” –Name “MyVM” | Get-AzureEndpoint
   ```

I would like to upload 4 GB files to the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

May be :

WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT = 2400 ?

and in your .config

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime executionTimeout="YourTime" maxRequestLength="YourSizeRequest"/>
</system.web>
```

-

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="<valueInBytes>"/>
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Added WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT = 3000 in Azure configuration, but still getting same Error 500 uploading 1.9 GB file. maxAllowedContentLength in web.config is set to 4294967295, bit less than 4GB